# C# передать Label в UserControl

Tags: c#, usercontrol, label

помогите пжл кто чем сможет :)
Есть форма авторизации

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboLogin.Text == "Вася" && txtPass.Text == "1111")
        {
            this.Hide();
            f1.lblRole.Text = comboLogin.Text;
            f1.Show();
        }
```

После авторизации, пользователь попадает на главную форму. Также на главной форме присутствует UserControl (там в основном DatagridView живет). Так вот, на главной форме есть label "lblRole", в свойствах выставлен Modifiers:public, Text:User None. В lblRole отображается кто вошел, тоисть Вася. 
А вот UserControl считывает вошедшего не Вася, а то что выставлено в свойствах lblRole главной формы, тисть UserNone.

Код в UserControl

```
private void b1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)// L O A D
        {
    frmMain fm = new frmMain();
                label1.Text = fm.lblRole.Text;
}
```

Вот собственно и сам вопрос, как получить кто вошел "Васю" а не свойства из lblRole в UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

Форма получения имени и пароля называется `FormLogin` кнопка `Отмена` в свойствах этой формы определена как `CancelButton`, код этой формы такой

```
public partial class FormLogin : Form
{
    public FormLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //считываем значения удаляя пробелы
        Name = _textBoxName.Text.Trim();
        Password = _textBoxPassword.Text.Trim();

        //проверяем
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите имя.", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return;
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите пароль.", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return;
        }

        //отдаем результат
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Главная форма программы имеет такой код

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Load += FormMain_Load;
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormLogin formLogin = new FormLogin();

        while (formLogin != null)
        {
            if (formLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (CheckUser(formLogin.Name, formLogin.Password))
                {
                    //присваиваем лейблу имя юзера
                    lblRole.Text = formLogin.Name;

                    //закрываем форму входа
                    formLogin.Close();
                    formLogin = null;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Неверное имя или пароль!", "Ошибка",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Закрыть программу?", "Вопрос",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    this.Close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private bool CheckUser(string name, string password)
    {
        return name.Equals("Вася") && password.Equals("123");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Bulson**, спс за ответ и ход мыслей, но, наверно я чуток не правильно изъяснился. Вот как обстоят у меня дела.
Код формы авторизации:

```
public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
        frmMain f1 = new frmMain();

        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Init_Data();
        }
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboLogin.Text == "Вася" && txtPass.Text == "1234")
            {
                this.Hide();
                f1.lblRole.Text = comboLogin.Text;
                f1.Show();
            }
else
            {

                txtPass.Clear();
                MessageBox.Show("##########");
            }
            Save_Data();
        }
```

Тут из comboBox передается имя вошедшего на главную форму в лайбел lblRole. И на главной форме показывает "Вася". Так как я говорил ранее, что присутствует еще UserControl на главной форме, в UserControl живет DataGridView.

Код из UserControl

```
private void b1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)// L O A D
        {
            this.addZayavkiTableAdapter.Fill(this.zayavkiDataSet.addZayavki);
            frmMain fm = new frmMain();

            if (fm.lblRole.Text == "Вася")
            {
                tsbSave.Enabled = false;
                btnDelete.Enabled = false;
                zayavkiDGV.ReadOnly = true;
                bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

При отладке видно, что UserControl получил не пользователя "Вася", а то, что задано в свойствах lblRole на главной форме
[image: Свойства lblRole]

Беда то заключается в том, что я не могу в UserControl'e получить имя, а получаю свойства лейбела, тоисть UserNone.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы используете ответы не по назначению. Пожалуйста, используйте возможность редактирования вопроса для его уточнения; а новые вопросы задавайте отдельно.

Comment: Я не совсем внимательно прочитал ваш код, а потому сделал свой пример по классике, с вводом имени, а не его выбором. Сути это не меняет, в моем примере достаточно изменить TextBox на ComboBox. Главное это то, что вы должны из главной формы запускать форму логина,  а не как у вас наоборот.

Comment: Bulson спс, вечерком попробую переиграть код. P.S. а в моем случае, никак не получится UserControl'у считать НЕ свойства? Такое ощущение, что надо допилить правельно if (fm.lblRole.Text == "Вася")

Comment: Попробовал я вашим кодом воспользоваться, та же история, UserControl считывает свойства, на выходе User None